# How to prove :$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_1.u_2...u_n}\right)^2=2011$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

For sequence $u_n$ satisfing : $$\begin{cases} u_1=\sqrt{2015}\\ u_{n+1}=u_n^2-2\end{cases}$$
How to prove : $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_1.u_2...u_n}\right)^2=2011$$

Comment: The Maple command $$rsolve(\{u(1) = 2015^{1/2}, u(n+1) = u(n)^2-2\}, u) $$ produces $$2\,\cosh \left( 1/2\,{\it arccosh} \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2015} \right) {2
}^{n} \right).
 $$

Comment: After simplification with Maple $$ \left( e^{\ln \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2015}+1/4\,\sqrt {-4+2\,
\sqrt {2015}}\sqrt {4+2\,\sqrt {2015}} \right) 2^n}+1 \right)*
 $$ $$ e^{-1/2\,\ln  \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2015}+1/4\,\sqrt {-4+2\,\sqrt 
{2015}}\sqrt {4+2\,\sqrt {2015}} \right) 2^n}

 $$

Comment: I'm surprised 'Maple' didn't do the further simplification that $e^{-1/2\ln(??)}=1/\sqrt{??}$.  And I wouldn't say that an expression of the form $e^{\ln(\dots)}$ is completely simplified....

Comment: Simplifying Maple's simplification in a few naive ways gives $u_n=\sqrt{2^n\left(\frac12\sqrt{2015}+\frac14\sqrt{2011}\right)}+\dfrac1
{\sqrt{2^n\left(\frac12\sqrt{2015}+
\frac14
\sqrt{2011}\right)}}$ (I wouldn't be surprised if you could simplify this further).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The recurrence relation may be expressed as
$$ 
{u_{n}}^2 = \frac{{u_{n+1}}^2 - 4}{{u_{n}}^2 - 4}.
$$

Which allows telescopic cancellation,

$$
\begin{align*}
\left ({u_{1}}{u_{2}}\cdots{u_{n}}\right )^2 &=
\left (\frac{\color{#036}{{u_{2}}^{2} - 4}}{{u_{1}}^2 - 4} \right )
\left ( \frac{\color{#063}{{u_{3}}^{2} - 4}}{\color{#036}{{u_{2}}^2 - 4}} \right )
\cdots
\left ( \frac{{u_{n+1}}^{2} - 4}{\color{#630}{{u_{n}}^2 - 4}} \right )\\[10pt]
&= \frac{{u_{n+1}}^2 - 4}{{u_{1}}^2 - 4}.
\end{align*}
$$

Hence,

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left ( \frac{u_{n+1}}{{u_{1}}{u_{2}}\cdots{u_{n}}} \right )^2
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} {u_{n+1}}^2 \cdot \frac{{u_{1}}^2 - 4}{{u_{n+1}}^2 - 4}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left ( {u_{1}}^2 - 4\right ) \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 4/{u_{n+1}}^2}\\
&= {u_{1}}^2 - 4 &\text{since $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/u_{n+1} = 0$}.
\end{align*}
$$

Substituting $u_1 = \sqrt{2015}$ yields the final result

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left ( \frac{u_{n+1}}{{u_{1}}{u_{2}}\cdots{u_{n}}} \right )^2 = 2011.$$

Answer (score 5):

Here I use its properties as an additive telescoping series:
$$\left(\frac{u_n^2-2}{u_1\cdots u_n}\right)^2=\frac{u_n^4}{(u_1\cdots u_n)^2}-\frac{4u_n^2}{(u_1\cdots u_n)^2}+\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_n)^2}$$
$$=\frac{u_n^2}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-1})^2}-\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-1})^2}+\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_n)^2}$$
Substitute again:
$$=\left(\frac{u_{n-1}^2}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-2})^2}-\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-2})^2}+\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-1})^2} \right)-\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-1})^2}+\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_n)^2}$$
$$=\frac{u_{n-1}^2}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-2})^2}-\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-2})^2}+\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_n)^2}$$
And again:
$$=\left(\frac{u_{n-2}^2}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-3})^2}-\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-3})^2}+\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-2})^2} \right)-\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-2})^2}+\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_n)^2}$$

$$=\frac{u_{n-2}^2}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-3})^2}-\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_{n-3})^2}+\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_n)^2}$$

Reapeat this process ad infinitum (noting that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}u_n= \infty$):

$$=\frac{u_{2}^2}{(u_1)^2}-\frac{4}{(u_1)^2}+\frac{4}{(u_1\cdots u_n)^2}$$

And take the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$:

$$=\frac{(2015-2)^2}{2015}-\frac{4}{2015}+0$$
$$=\frac{2015^2-4\cdot 2015 +4}{2015}-\frac{4}{2015}$$
$$=2015-4=2011$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{aligned}
u_{n+1} = {u_{n}}^2 - 2 \\
{u_{n+1}}^2 = ({u_{n}}^2 - 2)^2 \\
{u_{n+1}}^2 = {u_{n}}^4 - 4{u_{n}}^2 + 4 \\
{u_{n+1}}^2 - 4 = {u_{n}}^2({u_{n}}^2 - 4) \\
{u_{n}}^2 = \frac{{u_{n+1}}^2 - 4}{{u_{n}}^2 - 4}
\end{aligned}